# Camera2 API AutoFocus with Samsung S5

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working with the new Camera2 API on a Samsung S5. The supported hardware level this device is reporting is `LEGACY`, which is fine.

However, I cannot seem to be able to auto-focus on this device. The request to trigger auto-focus looks like this:

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
state = STATE_PREVIEW;
try {
  captureSession.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequestBuilder.build(), captureCallback, backgroundHandler);
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After the request is sent, the result of the request is always `CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN` and occasionally `CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED`.

The strange thing is that, when the state is `CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED`, the auto-focus goes back into the `CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN` state for a while and then back to `CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED`, resulting in a infinite focus loop. According to the docs, when state is `CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED`...

> The lens will remain stationary until the AF mode (android.control.afMode) is changed or a new AF trigger is sent to the camera device (android.control.afTrigger).

I'm wondering if this discrepancy is because of the fact that the hardware level is `LEGACY` and that I should go back to using the deprecated Camera API, but that seems crazy for such a prevalent feature such as auto focus.

Is there any reccomendations how how to treat devices that are reporting `LEGACY`?

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 15):

I branched form [google's Camera2Basic example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and changed it to use `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO` instead of `CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE`

You can take the project from git and test it - https://github.com/pinhassi/android-Camera2Basic

Or just add this to `Camera2BasicFragment`:

```
private static final long LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_FOCUSED = 5000;
private static final long LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_UNFOCUSED = 1000;

private Integer mLastAfState = null;
private Handler mUiHandler = new Handler(); // UI handler
private Runnable mLockAutoFocusRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lockAutoFocus();
    }
};


public void lockAutoFocus() {
    try {
        // This is how to tell the camera to lock focus.
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
        CaptureRequest captureRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, null); // prevent CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START from calling over and over again
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private float getMinimumFocusDistance() {
    if (mCameraId == null)
        return 0;

    Float minimumLens = null;
    try {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics c = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
        minimumLens = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "isHardwareLevelSupported Error", e);
    }
    if (minimumLens != null)
        return minimumLens;
    return 0;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
private boolean isAutoFocusSupported() {
    return  isHardwareLevelSupported(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY) || getMinimumFocusDistance() > 0;
}

// Returns true if the device supports the required hardware level, or better.
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private boolean isHardwareLevelSupported(int requiredLevel) {
    boolean res = false;
    if (mCameraId == null)
        return res;
    try {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);

        int deviceLevel = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
        switch (deviceLevel) {
            case CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3:
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera support level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3");
                break;
            case CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL:
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera support level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL");
                break;
            case CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY:
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera support level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY");
                break;
            case CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED:
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera support level: INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL: " + deviceLevel);
                break;
        }


        if (deviceLevel == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY) {
            res = requiredLevel == deviceLevel;
        } else {
            // deviceLevel is not LEGACY, can use numerical sort
            res = requiredLevel <= deviceLevel;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "isHardwareLevelSupported Error", e);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then, add to `STATE_PREVIEW` block:

```
        case STATE_PREVIEW: {

            // We have nothing to do when the camera preview is working normally.
            // TODO: handle auto focus
            Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
            if (afState != null && !afState.equals(mLastAfState)) {
                switch (afState) {
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE:
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_INACTIVE");
                        lockAutoFocus();
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN:
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN");
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED");
                        mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(mLockAutoFocusRunnable);
                        mUiHandler.postDelayed(mLockAutoFocusRunnable, LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_FOCUSED);
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED:
                        mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(mLockAutoFocusRunnable);
                        mUiHandler.postDelayed(mLockAutoFocusRunnable, LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_UNFOCUSED);
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED");
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_UNFOCUSED:
                        mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(mLockAutoFocusRunnable);
                        //mUiHandler.postDelayed(mLockAutoFocusRunnable, LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_UNFOCUSED);
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_UNFOCUSED");
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_SCAN:
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_SCAN");
                        break;
                    case CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED:
                        mUiHandler.removeCallbacks(mLockAutoFocusRunnable);
                        //mUiHandler.postDelayed(mLockAutoFocusRunnable, LOCK_FOCUS_DELAY_ON_FOCUSED);
                        Log.d(TAG, "CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_PASSIVE_FOCUSED");
                        break;
                }
            }
            mLastAfState = afState;
            break;
        }
```

And replace all occurrences of:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                            CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
```

With:

```
if (isAutoFocusSupported())
                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
                            else
                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
```

Comment: @AlexShcherbyna for me it did work just fine. what further adjustments did you make though?

Comment: @Entertain, next step was like this

```if(supportsContinuousAutoFocus(activity, mCameraId)){

                        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                    }
                    else {
                        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
                        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your setRepeatingRequest. As far as I know, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO should only cause an autofocus to occur once, but setRepeatingRequest will send continuous requests. Try using capture instead:

```
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO);
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);

state = STATE_PREVIEW;

try {
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mPreCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: This is what I do as well, however, I found that since 2nd attempt to take picture, afState is always 0 (INACTIVE) instead of 4 or 5 (LOCKED)

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue with a Galaxy Note 4 running Android 5.1.1 - while the same code works fine on a variety of other Android devices. There have been reports of similar issues with Galaxy-S4/S5/S6.

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=289824&startId=zzzzz~
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnMoYZwVaFM

So to anwer you question: This is most likely a bug in Samsung's implementation of the Camera-2 implementation - which seems to be of very low quality, unfourtunately.

Answer (score -3):

The Samsung S5 with autofocus returned `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY`, which means it does not support `Camera2` api.

I have the below filter for using camera in my application.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 &amp;&amp; isDeviceCompatibleOfCamera2()) {
 // Use camera2
} else {
 // Use old camera
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
 public boolean isDeviceCompatibleOfCamera2() {
 try {
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    String backCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    CameraCharacteristics backCameraInfo = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(backCameraId);

    int level = backCameraInfo.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
    return level == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL;

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
     ETLog.d(TAG, &quot;Device not compatible of camera2 api&quot; + e);
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. LEGACY hardware support has nothing to do with auto-focus, -exposure, or -white balance, it has to do basically with manual sensor control. Legacy devices can (and do) still have auto controls, if you use them correctly. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL

Comment: How can you tell if CONTROL_AF_MODE_AUTO is supported? by getting LENS_INFO_MINIMUM_FOCUS_DISTANCE value, which is availvable only with hardware support > LEGACY